# WooCommerce: change category checkboxes to drop-downs

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Help me, please!

I need to change the category check-boxes to drop-down on the WooCommerce add product page. The user should be able choose only one category.

When the user chooses a category, all subcategories of the chosen category should be in the next drop-down. The user should be able to choose only one subcategory.

Then I need to put this two drop-downs under "Product Data" drop-down.

1. How do I remove "Product Categories" block?
2. How do I add categories drop-down to the "Product Data" block?
3. How do I put subcategories in the second drop-down dependent on the category selected in the first drop-down?

[image: Categories Image]

Comment: The thing you are asking for is a lot of development job. It is not just a question for a problem you have stucked during your job. For this you have to modify the plugin so better you find a developer to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do I remove "Product Categories" block?

   ```
   function remove_custom_meta_box() {
       remove_meta_box('{taxonomy-name}div', 'product', 'side');
   }
   add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_custom_meta_box');
   ```
2. How do I add categories drop-down to the "Product Data" block?

   and
3. How do I put subcategories in the second drop-down dependent on the category selected in the first drop-down?

   ```
   function categories_dropdown_metabox() {
       add_meta_box('custom-taxonomy-dropdown', 'Product Category', 'taxonomy_dropdowns_box', 'product', 'side', 'high');
   }

   function taxonomy_dropdowns_box($post) {
       $terms        = get_terms('product_cat', 'hide_empty=0');
       $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array('fields'=>'ids'));

       <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               jQuery('#product-category').change(function() {
                   var product = jQuery('#product-category').val();
                   if ( product == '0') {
                       jQuery('#prodcatoptions').html('');
                           jQuery('#categorycontainer').css('display', 'none');
                   } else {
                       var data = {
                           'action':'get_product_categories',
                           'product':product,
                           'dropdown-nonce': jQuery('#dropdown-nonce').val()
                       };
                       jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
                           jQuery('#prodcatoptions').html(response);
                           jQuery('#categorycontainer').css('display', 'inline');
                       });
                   }
               });
           });
       </script>       

       <div> 
           <span>Category:</span>
           <select required id='product-category' name='prodcategory[]'>
               <option value=''>Choose category</option>
               <?php
               foreach ($terms as $term) {
                   if ($term->parent == 0) {
                       if (in_array($term->term_id, $object_terms)) {
                           $parent_id = $term->term_id;
                           echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$term->name}</option>";
                       } else {
                           echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</option>";
                       }
                   }
               }
               ?>
           </select>
       </div>
       <div id='categorycontainer' <?php if (!isset($parent_id)) { echo "style='display: none;'"; }?> >
           <span>Subcategory:</span>
           <select required id='prodcatoptions' name='prodcategory[]'>
               <?php
               if (isset($parent_id)) {
                   $models = get_terms('product_cat', 'hide_empty=0&child_of='.$parent_id);

                   foreach ($models as $model) {
                       if (in_array($model->term_id, $object_terms)) {
                           echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$model->name}</option>";
                       } else {
                           echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}'>{$model->name}</option>";
                       }
                   }

               }
               ?>
           </select>
       </div>
       <?php
   }

   add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'categories_dropdown_metabox');

   function save_my_custom_taxonomy($post_id) {
       if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
           return;
       }    
       if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dropdown-nonce'], 'custom-dropdown')) {
           return;
       }  
       $product_cat = array_map('intval', $_POST['prodcategory']);
       wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $product_cat, 'product_cat');
   }

   add_action('save_post','save_my_custom_taxonomy');

   function get_product_categories() {
       check_ajax_referer('custom-dropdown', 'dropdown-nonce');
       if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
           $models = get_terms('product_cat', 'hide_empty=0&child_of='. $_POST['product']);
           echo "<option value=''>Choose subcategory</option>";
           foreach ($models as $model) {
               echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}'>{$model->name}</option>";
           }
       }
       die();
   }

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_product_categories', 'get_product_categories' );
   ```